# Mysql printing table onto html using freemarker

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, freemarker

My main servlet containing getting into the mysql database and receiving the data.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DatabaseAccess.closeConnection(con);
    }
```

My viewtables.ftl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>IMDB SEARCHER</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am having trouble how to print the result tables onto the html while using freemarker. I am using the imdb database and trying to print out the movies table onto my html when user searches for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the data of the result set into `root`, then process the template.

I would create a Class `Row`

```
public class Row{
    String id, name, year, rank;
    //constructor, getters and setters follow
}
```

Fill an array list of rows

```
List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
while(rs.next()) {
    Row row = new Row(rs.getString("id"),rs.getString("name"),rs.getString("year"),rs.getString("rank"));
    rows.add(row);
}
root.put("rows", rows);
```

Now that the list of rows is accessible you have to print it out in your template

```
<h3>${tableName} search results</h3>
<table class = 'ResultSet'>
    <#list rows as row >
        <tr>
            <td>${row.id}</td>
            <td>${row.name}</td>
            <td>${row.year}</td>
            <td>${row.rank}</td>
        </tr>
    </#list>
</div>
```